# How to make when generating a pdf, this one opens automatically in a window, TCPDF?

Tags: jquery, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm working with jquery and within a routine, I invoke a new window, window.open (), which draws a table with data stored in the database. There is also a button in this new window that allows to generate a pdf with the information of the displayed table. The issue is that when the pdf is generated, a window opens (common dialog I believe it is called) to save the file on the computer, then go to the directory and open the pdf. This behavior is not what is required. What is required is that when the pdf is generated, it will automatically open in the new window, so that it can be recorded or sent to print.

The final part of the PDF generation is:

```
  $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
  $serial='123';
  $nombre='Archivo_'.$serial.'_'.date("d-m-Y H-i-s");
  $obj_pdf->Output($nombre, 'I');
```

Please can someone help me with this topic?
From already thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file name `$nombre` has the `.pdf` extension at the end

```
$nombre='Archivo_'.$serial.'_'.date("d-m-Y H-i-s").'.pdf';
```

Have you tried adding a content type header to your response?

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Also make sure your browser has a PDF plugin installed https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1